# Rotational work by a force

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, work, rigid-body-dynamics

If we have an object which is acted upon by a force which which produces both translational and rotational motion of body then would the total work done by the force be the sum of its translational and rotational work?

Comment: The total work done would be equal to the change in KE of the body, which includes both rotational as well as translational KE. However, without specifying the type of force, and details of where and how it's acting on the body, its hard to say whether the force is doing positive, zero or negative work.

Comment: @wonderingwhy If I want to use the WET for this situation, I write the sum of translational and rotational KE on RHS, then what do I write on the LHS? Do I write the sum of translational and rotational work of the force? I hope u can understand my question cuz noone has been able to understand what I am asking till now

Comment: Pleas do not use abbreviations like WET ,RHS LHS which not everybody understands,

Comment: @yyzr See my answer to your other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/808061/doubt-in-rotational-work-energy-theorem. There is no such thing as "rotational work" or "translational work". Work is work and energy is energy. In fact, we can go further - "work" and "energy" are just two names for the same thing, which is the whole point of the work-energy theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we have an object which is acted upon by a force which which
> produces both translational and rotational motion of body then would
> the total work done by the force be the sum of its translational and
> rotational work?

There may be semantic issues here and it would perhaps to clearer to talk in terms of energy which is equivalent to work. If we assume the body initially has zero linear and angular energy, then its final total energy $E_T$ of the body after the application of the force is
$$E_T = E_L + E_R = \frac12 m v^2 + \frac12 I \omega^2$$

where $E_L$ is the linear energy $E_R$ is the rotational energy, $I$ is the moment of inertia, m is the mass,$\omega$ is the angular velocity and v is the linear velocity of the body.

If we assume conditions where no energy is lost as heat etc, then the final total energy must be equal to the energy input by the original force acting over a distance d, where for simplicity we consider the force to be constant.

The input energy is equal to F d and we could call this the linear work done on the system. Since torque is $FR$ we can alternatively express this input energy as $F R \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle the object rotates through, during the application of the force and call this the input rotational work, but they are the same thing expressed in different ways and we should be careful not to double count and assume the total input work is $F d + F R \omega$ as that would cause an error.

P.S. I am working on a more detailed answer to the question you posed in a comment to my answer in a [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/807920/rotation-of-disc-on-smooth-surface/807956?noredirect=1#comment1814956_807956), so stand by :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the ***net*** force acting on a body is responsible for producing both translational and rotational kinetic energy of the body, then one can say the total work done by the *net* force on the body is the sum of the work done by the net force to produce the translational kinetic energy plus the work done by the net force to produce the rotational kinetic energy.

However, one cannot say that any one given force is responsible for the translational or rotational  kinetic energy without knowing the details of the interaction of the force with the body. That's because it is possible for a force to enable a body to accelerate without necessarily doing work on (transferring any energy to) the body.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "That's because it is possible for a force to enable a body to accelerate without necessarily doing work on (transferring any energy to) the body." Example?

Comment: @Not_Einstein Yes. An ice skater pushes off a wall on the rink accelerating the ice skater backwards. The reaction force of the wall enables the acceleration, but the wall does no work (the wall transfers no energy to the skater). A person jumps up from the ground. The reacting force of the ground enables the jumper to accelerate up, but the ground does no work on (transfers no energy to) the jumper

Comment: So we can explain the ice skater acceleration as a change in momentum due to the impulse of the reaction force of the wall over a period of time. As for work done by a force, it's sufficient to cause acceleration but not necessary.